# getElementsByClassName in ClojureScript?

Tags: clojure, clojurescript

I want to select several items in

> ClojureScript

, but can't! How can I get them in CLJS?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Show some CLJS code with the accompanying HTML.

Answer (score 9):

Have you tried using `(.getElementsByClassName js/document "class-name")`?

This will return a HTMLCollection JS object, so if you want to convert it
to a seq, use something like:

```
(array-seq (.getElementsByClassName js/document "class-name"))
```

Also, as a side note, if you want to make HTMLCollection ISeqable, which is a little  more idiomatic, check out this other post. [Why aren't NodeList / HtmlCollection seqable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23616019/why-arent-nodelist-htmlcollection-seqable)